# who create API for drupal site to get content and used in mobile app?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

i create function (sbt_conten_post_by_type_json) in > sites > all > modules > content > content-module

and in same file i added (sbt_conten_post_by_type_json) function in menu-hook

```
$items['sbt_conten_post_by_type_json'] = array(
'page callback' => 'sbt_conten_post_by_type_json',
'access arguments' => array('view_json'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

but when open  My_Domin/sbt_conten_post_by_type_json

Nothing happens

why  ?  Is there anything else should I add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your module you have to make new directory in `sites/all/modules/my_module`

Inside you place your `my_module.module` file containing your module code and `my_module.info` file describing your module. When you do that, on your back-end modules page your module should be visible, but not active. You have to activate it in order to use it.

https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7

Comment: When you are logged in as admin in main admin menu there is a "Modules" link. Click it and you'll end up on modules page:

Root relative path is :"/admin/modules"  (without quotes).

Now scroll down (or use search) until you find your module. Enable it by clicking check box in first column...next to your module and go to the bottom of that page and click "Save configuration"